# Cannot access selenium hub running in docker container from pc browser using localhost

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-grid, docker-network

I am making selenium grid using docker(for windows) with following docker images:

selenium/hub

selenium/node-chrome-debug

selenium/node-firefox-debug

I ran these using docker networking with following commands:

```
$ docker network create grid
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --net grid --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
```

The output of `docker -ps` is:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID       IMAGE       COMMAND        CREATED    
STATUS             PORTS       NAMES
037a7950c73a  selenium/hub "/opt/bin/entry_poin"   33 minutes ago
Up 33 minutes 0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp   selenium-hub
```

But when I try to access hub in windows pc in chrome browser using http://localhost:4444/gid/console it is showing "site cannot be reached".

I tried using ip address of my computer using ipconfig but still it gives site cannot be reached.

Any solution?

Edit: I am using docker toolbox on windows7.

Comment: You are mentioning Windows pc but your prompt `$` looks more like Linux one..

Comment: @AlexeyR. This prompt is from the docker quickstart terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ip address shown while starting the quickstart terminal as shown in following figure:[image]